# A number which can be factored into a product of $k$ and $k+2$ consecutive natural numbers (each $>1$)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> We say that the number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ has the property $P(k)$ if it can be factored into a product of $k$ consecutive natural numbers (not equal to $1$).
>
> Find the value of $k$ such that some $N$ simultaneously has the properties $P(k)$ and $P(k+2)$.

This is a problem from a Soviet high-school math contest (1981).

The book I found it in only offers the following answer:

> $$k=3;~~720=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6=8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10$$

**Is this the only solution?**

**How can this problem be solved in general?** (Using high-school level math)

---

My attempt. For some $n(N,k), m(N,k) \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$N=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

$$N=\frac{m!}{(m-k-2)!}$$

Obviously:

$$m<n$$

So it seems to me we have a three variable equation which needs to be solved in natural numbers $m,n,k$:

$$\frac{n!}{m!}=\frac{(n-k)!}{(m-k-2)!}$$

I'm not sure how this can be solved.

I suppose we can also write:

$$\frac{N}{k!}=\left( \begin{array}( n \\ k \end{array} \right)$$

$$\frac{N}{(k+2)!}=\left( \begin{array}( ~~~m \\ k+2 \end{array} \right)$$

So:

$$(k+1)(k+2)\left( \begin{array}( ~~~m \\ k+2 \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}( n \\ k \end{array} \right)$$

---

**Edit**

By abusing Mathematica I found several other solutions (see also @stewbasic's comment):

$$k=20,~~~~n=24,~~~~m=23,~~~~N=25852016738884976640000$$

$$k=55,~~~~n=60,~~~~m=59,~~~~N= \text{a very big number}$$

I wonder, do all the solutions except for $k=3$ and $k=4$ obey the rule:

$$n=m+1$$

For this case we can easily write:

$$m+1=\frac{(m-k+1)!}{(m-k-2)!}=(m-k-1)(m-k)(m-k+1)$$

So we get a Diophantine equation:

$$   m^3- 3 k m^2+ 3 k^2 m - 2 m-1 + k - k^3=0$$

> $$(m-k)^3=2m+1-k$$

This one has many solutions, it seems, for example:

$$k=328,~~~~m=335$$

$$k=495,~~~~m=503$$

$$k=710,~~~~m=719$$

---

Al of this doesn't answer my question - how high-schoolers were supposed to solve this problem?

Also, **is there only one $N$ for each $k$ in general**? How to show this if true?

Comment: It's not the only solution; multiplying your equality by 7 gives $5040=2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7=7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10$.

Comment: @stewbasic, thank you, missed the obvious

Comment: Perhaps the problem was meant to ask for the **least** value of $k > 1$?  Then all you need to do is rule out $k=2$ and  find one solution for $k=3$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, it's possible, but in my book there is no such clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer solutions of your equation (in the case $n=m+1$) $(m-k)^3 = 2m+1-k$ are obtained by solving a system of linear equations in $m$ and $k$:
$$ \eqalign{t &= m-k\cr 
            t^3 &= 2m + 1 - k\cr}$$
to get
$$ m = t^3 - t - 1, \ k = t^3 - 2 t - 1 $$
This gives you positive integer values of $m$ and $k$ iff $t$ is an integer $\ge 2$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea how to solve this problem completely?

Comment: I do not.  It looks hard: the equation you get for fixed positive integer $n-m>1$ is an algebraic curve which seems to have genus $> 1$.  If so, there should be only finitely many integer solutions for each $n-m$, but I don't know if there are finitely many of these exceptional solutions in all.